# ajax response is getting lost after unsuccessful form submission in java webapp

Tags: java, ajax, forms, web-applications, response

I have a form with fields which are getting populated from ajax response, but here is the problem when i submit the form with some validation errors then the form submission is getting failed as expected, but i'm unable to regain the same form with fields which are already populated through ajax response.they are displaying the state to the initial form load.

```
private ActionResult updateAlertTemplate(final Control source,
        final JQEvent event, final String globalFormatYN, final Form form) {
    final JQTaconite actionResult = new JQTaconite();
    new WithTransaction<Object>() {
        @Override
        protected Object execute0(final DatabaseSession s,
                final Object... args) {
            final Field sel = form.getField("format");
            if (globalFormatYN.equals("G")) {
                final String eventcode = (String) getContext().getSession()
                        .getAttribute("eventCode0");
                final String channel = (String) getContext().getSession()
                        .getAttribute("channel0");
                ProgramUtils.fillAlertTemplate(s, sel, eventcode, channel);
            }
            // sel.setStyle("width", "200px");
            actionResult.replace(sel);
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
    return actionResult;
} its an apache click code
```

Comment: please provide relevant code.

Comment: Can you tell us what you have already tried?

Comment: the above method returns the ajax response for one of the field in a form, there are some more fields are there where some are mandatory.
without entering mandatory field values when i submit the form, i am able to get proper error messages but i am losing the already loaded ajax response for the field in form.